# How do I use different config for testing vs. deployment hardhat solidity?

Tags: testing, deployment, config, solidity, hardhat

Right now, when using hardhat, I have a different config for testing and deployment. Currently I am changing the file name depending on whether I am testing or deploying. This does not seem optimal/correct.

Does anyone know a way I can specify which to use? Or even better, a way to specify in the config testing vs deployment?

Testing config:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
};
```

Deployment config:

```
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
const {API_URL, METAMASK_PRIVATE_KEY} = process.env;
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
  defaultNetwork: "rinkeby",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    rinkeby: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${METAMASK_PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  },
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
};
```

I guess really I just want to ignore the "networks" field when testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized the only difference between these configs was the network flag, for testing I wanted to use the hardhat network, and deployment, rinkeby.

Changing the default network param to:

```
defaultNetwork: "Hardhat"
```

allowed me to run tests on the hardhat network using the `npx hardhat test` command.

Then deploying I can use:

```
npx hardhat run --network rinkeby scripts/deploy.js
```

Comment: hi @Lucas is it work? because when I did this it gives me the same error while running `npx hardhat test`

Comment: Yes this works. What error are you getting?