# I want to run hardhat tests for local network not on testnet, how to configure it?

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

So the problem is I have defined a hardhat config like this

```js
import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
})

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    // defined defaultNetwork as hardhat so it would use it for testing.
    defaultNetwork: {
      url: 'hardhat',
    },
    hardhat: {},
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.STAGING_QUICKNODE_KEY,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY!]
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

when I run this command on my local machine `npx hardhat test` it works fine because I guess maybe I have a `.env` file, but if I remove this `.env` file or run this command on `GitHub workflow` it would give me this error.

```
Error HH8: There are one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.goerli.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid account: #0 for the network: goerli - Expected string, received undefined
```

now the problem is I don't want to upload my `.env` file on GitHub because it contains my secret key information. I have seen this answer as well and tried it also [How do I use different config for testing vs. deployment hardhat solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806740/how-do-i-use-different-config-for-testing-vs-deployment-hardhat-solidity)

so I tried to run this command `npx hardhat test --network hardhat` but it would the same error as above.

I want to know if there is any way to change this `config` object at runtime in `*.spec.ts` files, then I can try that way or if you know of any other hacks, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors mentioned in your question are related to the fact that the config values are invalid. Hardhat expects the `accounts` items to be of type `string` (and in the format of "`0x` followed by 64 hex characters") but they are `undefined`.

I'm not sure about the proper solution (anyone else feel free to provide a better answer), but you can use a dummy key as a workaround.

```
goerli: {
  url: process.env.STAGING_QUICKNODE_KEY || "https://dummy.url.com",
  accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || "0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234"]
}
```

---

This validation happens before running the tests. So even if you use the `hardhat` network for tests, it won't allow you to run them if another part of the config is invalid.

`npx hardhat test` and `npx hardhat test --network hardhat` is effectively the same command, as `hardhat` is the default network.

Comment: yep, this would work, thanks for your answer but one little modification would be needed which is to change it for the URL as well.

Comment: This is good working. I can't find another way. If want to insert the real key (private or Infura URI), you should use the GitHub secret key.